# pass a variable from one javascript file to another javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my small code snippet to send the request message to the server and get back the response and prints it. It's a chrome add-on but the thing is if any onClick operations will happen on the browser then it will grab the url and has to send to the another JavaScript file  then this JavaScript file is responsible for sending url to the node.js server

the url.js(which grabs the url on click) file is :

```
$(document).click(function (e) {

    if ($(e.target).closest('a').length) {
        // I want this url variable to be transferred from here to the below
        // JavaScript file
        var url = $(e.target).closest('a').attr('href');
    } else {
        alert('You did not click a link');
    }
});
```

and the other javascript file which takes the parameter is  :

```
window.WebSocket = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:1337');

connection.onopen = function () {
    connection.send(url);
    connection.send("http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/bd294ce7ff4c43b6aad4aa4169fb819b.jpg");
};

connection.onerror = function (error) {
    alert("something went wrong with your server  " + error);
};

connection.onclose = function () {
    alert("server had shut down now ");
};

connection.onmessage = function (message) {

    try {
        var json = JSON.parse(message.data);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('This doesn\'t look like a valid JSON: ', message.data);
        return;
    }
    if (json.type === 'message') {

        addMessage(json.data.text);

    } else {
        console.log('Hmm..., I\'ve never seen JSON like this: ', json);
    }
};

function addMessage(message) {

    var rec_object = message;
    var regexp1 = /[\/a-zA-Z]+(.jpg)/;
    var regexp2 = /[\/a-zA-Z]+(.mp3)/;
    var regexp3 = /[\/a-zA-Z]+(.mp4)/;
    if (regexp1.test(rec_object)) {
        document.write("<img width=\"300\" height=\"250\" src=\"" + rec_object + "\" \/>")
        document.write("<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />");
    } else
    if (regexp2.test(rec_object)) {
        document.write("<audio controls>");
        document.write("<source src=\"" + rec_object + "\"type=audio\/mpeg \/>");
        document.write("</audio>");
        document.write("<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />");
    } else
    if (regexp3.test(rec_object)) {
        document.write("<video width=\"300\" height=\"250\" controls>")
        document.write("<source src=\"" + rec_object + "\"type=video\/mp4 \/>");
        document.write("</video>");
    } else
        document.write(rec_object);

}
```

So how can I do it with out using query string? I just want to send it from one file to another file. I tried like above but I was not getting anything.

Comment: Please, at least [beautify](http://jsbeautifier.org/) your code before posting... ;)

Answer (score 0):

In place of the following:

```
var url = $(e.target).closest('a').attr('href');
```

use a global variable:

```
window.url = $(e.target).closest('a').attr('href');
```

Then, in your other file also, use `connection.send(window.url)`. This will get you going but read below.

***Note::*** Using global variables is a very bad practice. Ideally, I'd restructure your code to create a `Connection` object with a property named `url` which is instantiated from within the callback and then you can simple call whatever methods you want to call on it. All its methods will work with the local variable `url`.

Comment: how to do it ?  I actually it's regarding my project and I have to submit it today by 4 .  I tried the code like you have given above but now its displaying browser like "  undefined  "

Comment: So, this is a homework assignment? I'm suddenly suspecting that you have not written the other pieces of the code either because they need a good deal of Javascript understanding. Heck, you are using `window.WebSocket`. You definitely understand what does `window` represent, don't you?

Comment: No sir it's not like that I was trying from past 10 days

Comment: with out writing that window.WebSocket also we can run it just we are giving the information regarding the browser we are going to use